# three.js: Apply external texture to glTF

Tags: javascript, three.js, model, 3d, textures

I have two files: "model.gltf" and "texture.jpeg". I want to apply texture file to model and render it using three.js but after 3 days of continuous research and hundreds of attempts, I just can't get it to work properly. My method that sets the current object in the scene:

```js
/**
 * SET method: Sets object in the scene (deleting previous one)
 * 
 * @author Anton Pernisch <anton@pernisch.dev>
 * @param {string} modelPath - Path to object in glTF format
 * @param {string} texturePath - Path to texture
 * @returns {boolean}
 * 
 * @todo Texture
 */
SET_Object: function(modelPath, texturePath) {
    // Clear out the scene
    for (var i = this.prodconf3_scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        obj = this.prodconf3_scene.children[i];
        this.prodconf3_scene.remove(obj); 
    }

    const modelLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

    modelLoader.load(modelPath, (gltf) => {
        // HERE? apply texture from texturePath to this gltf

        this.prodconf3_obj = gltf.scene;
        this.prodconf3_scene.add(this.prodconf3_obj);
    });
    
    return true;
}
```

This code imports glTF just fine, it's just black. Eventually, I was able to apply .jpeg texture to this model, but only sort of. This is the best result I could get:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICjQt.png)

And that was by this method:

```js
/**
 * SET method: Sets current object to scene (deleting previous one)
 * 
 * @author Anton Pernisch <anton@pernisch.dev>
 * @param {string} modelPath - Path to object in glTF format
 * @param {string} texturePath - Path to texture
 * @returns {boolean}
 * 
 * @todo Texture
 */
SET_Object: function(modelPath, texturePath) {
    // Clear out the scene
    for (var i = this.prodconf3_scene.children.length - 1; i >=0 ; i--) { 
        obj = this.prodconf3_scene.children[i];
        this.prodconf3_scene.remove(obj); 
    }

    const modelLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    modelLoader.load(modelPath, (gltf) => {
        var model = gltf.scene;
        model.traverse((o) => {
            if (o.isMesh) {
                o.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: textureLoader.load(texturePath)});
            }
        });

        this.prodconf3_obj = model;
        this.prodconf3_scene.add(this.prodconf3_obj);
    });
    
    return true;
}
```

I have also tried creating texture by TextureLoader load method and then meshing it together with `gltf.scene` from `modelLoader.load` function. That didn't work at all, I was getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'center' of undefined

error (I'm not sure about using `gltf.scene` as the first argument in `THREE.Mesh()` tho).

**So, my question is, what is the proper and updated approach to properly apply the texture to glTF in three.js?**

Comment: At first glance, your code looks like it should work. What do you get when you console.log `textureLoader.load(texturePath)`?

Comment: It will return `Texture` object, just like [this](https://ibb.co/QfFVtTc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks fine to me, but I wonder if we're supposed to pass a reference to an already loaded texture.

[`Object3D#Traverse`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r125/src/core/Object3D.js#L523) isn't asynchronous, so we'll have to update the material synchronously.

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/three-panorama-forked-sk41h?file=/index.js:942-1095).

```js
SET_Object: async function(modelPath, texturePath) {
    // Clear out the scene
    for (let i = this.prodconf3_scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) { 
        obj = this.prodconf3_scene.children[i];
        this.prodconf3_scene.remove(obj); 
    }

    const modelLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    // Load texture
    const texture = await textureLoader.loadAsync(texturePath);
    texture.flipY = false;

    // Load model
    const { scene: model } = await modelLoader.loadAsync(modelPath);

    // Update model
    model.traverse((o) => {
        if (o.isMesh) {
            o.material.map = texture;
            o.material.needsUpdate = true;
        }
    });

    this.prodconf3_obj = model;
    this.prodconf3_scene.add(this.prodconf3_obj);
    
    return this.prodconf3_obj;
}
```

Comment: You'll need to set `texture.flipY = false`, and it might be good to avoid loading the same texture multiple times if the model has more than one mesh. Also note that if you're replacing an entire material, you'll need to be aware of important options (vertexColors, vertexTangents, morphTargets, skinning) that might have been enabled on the original material and copy them over.